Angular 16: Solve Error NG8001: 'component' is not a known element for component already imported in the module
I generated two components, HomeMainComponent and QuestComponent. I also generated their modules, HomeMainModule and QuestModule.
Folder Structure looks like this:
- src
-- app
--- components
----- home
------ home-main
------ quest

I'm adding components in their respective modules' export array:
In home-main.module.ts:
  exports: [HomeMainComponent],
In quest.module.ts:
  exports: [QuestComponent],
I'm sure I explicitly imported the components with the correct paths.
Now, I import the QuestModule into the home-main.module.ts file to add it to the module imports array.
in home-main.module.ts file:
  imports: [CommonModule, QuestModule],
With this, I make available the app-quest selector in the home-main.component.html file.
<p>home-main works!</p>
<app-quest></app-quest>


However, I get an error Failed to compile. Error: src/app/components/home/home-main/home-main.component.html:2:1 - error NG8001: 'app-quest' is not a known element.
I had been using this pattern without problems before.
If it helps to know, the first time I generated those components I tried to manually rename folder and files for the QuestComponent, got this error and I decided to delete both components and regenerate them. VSC doesn't show any errors, but I get it when running ng serve.

I tried regenerating the component and module files.
I checked all of the paths of the imports and selectors names.
I've made sure that my components are declared in their respective
modules and exported.
I stopped development server and started it again (ng serve).
I deleted .angular and node_modules folders, ran npm i and ng serve.
I didn't install any package when this error ocurred.

The only thing I did differently was trying to manually rename folder and files for a generated module and component. However, I deleted them and regenerated them from scratch.

Please add full code of your components and modules, because from what you wrote, everything should work fine. Or you could reproduce it on stackblitz

Sorry. I didn't make any changes to the code, however today I ran ng serve and now it works.
